# Accessing Data From ArrayList

Tags: java

I m working on populating a list dynamically with dynamic rows and columns and showing them in UI.  All have been done accurately but i m unable to get value from a specified row and column e.g. row 4 and column 3.  Code is as under:-

```
    public LiveRangeService() {
    tableData = new ArrayList< Map<String, ColumnModel> >();

    //Generate table header.
    tableHeaderNames = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          tableHeaderNames.add(new ColumnModel("header "+j, " col:"+ String.valueOf(j+1)));
    }

    //Generate table data.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Map<String, ColumnModel> playlist = new HashMap<String, ColumnModel>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            playlist.put(tableHeaderNames.get(j).key, new ColumnModel(tableHeaderNames.get(j).key,"row:" + String.valueOf(i+1) +" col:"+ String.valueOf(j+1)));
        }
        tableData.add(playlist);
    }
    try {
        System.out.println( "Table Data Size " + tableData.size() );
        System.out.println( "Value Of Row 1 Col 2: " + tableData.get(1).get(2) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "Error!! " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

may some body pls help me in understanding this chunk of code.  Error occurs on the following line:-

```
            System.out.println( "Value Of Row 1 Col 2: " + tableData.get(1).get(2) );
```

[the result shown on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jzUg.png)

Comment: What is your error, IndexOutOfBound?? Please also upload your error console log too!

Comment: it gives Null error if embedded in try catch.

Comment: So what do you want? any exception ?

Comment: He wants to know that java counts from 0, and that `someArray[0]` is the first element of an array. (same concept for ArrayList)

Comment: i want to get any element from the above mentioned filled data.  the is shown accurately on page but i can't figure out how to access data from the array list.

Comment: Your tableData is `ArrayList<Map<String, ColumnModel>>`, so `tableData.get(1).get(2)` doesn't mean to retrieve the 2nd column but the column whose key is 2.

Comment: LHCHIN: i understand it there, the key and the column index is same but any how, i can't access, may u help me to get an element from the a.m. ArrayList??

Comment: Then you should use `tableData.get(1).get("2")` not `tableData.get(1).get(2)`. As I said, your tableData is `ArrayList<Map<String, ColumnModel>>`.

Comment: public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {

    String key;
    private String value;

    public ColumnModel() {
        
    }

    public ColumnModel(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

Column Model has given pasted above but tableData.get(1).get("2").getValue() give error, tableData.get(1).get("2") give same error.

Comment: Thank you very much LHCHIN, its great help, the key was header 0, header 1 etc and it worked great.  finally i wrote: tableData.get(1).get("header 2").getValue() and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableData = new ArrayList< Map<String, ColumnModel> >();
```

you are storing maps in list and this map is of generic 
means key in map is String.

```
tableData.get(1).get(2)
```

This above line **get(1)** will give you first Map object.
then **get(2)**, means you are passing **Integer** as key to fetch value from map but your map needs **String** as key.

Its map and value can be retrieved using key and not based on index like arrayList. so you are getting error

pass something like

```
tableData.get(1).get(<some string key>)
```

it should work

Comment: thanx, thats the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Java counts starting from 0.

`tableData.get(0).get(0)` will get the element at row 1, and column 1. The `ArrayList` containing `Map`s starts from 0. However, `tableData.get(tableData.size())` will throw an error, as it will contain the number of elements in the ArrayList. (So, if an array had 3 elements, `tableData.size()` would return 3 and you would be able to call for it by calling for `tableData.get(2)`)

`tableData.get(1).get(2)` will get the element at row 2, and column 3.

To get the value of the element at row 1, column 2, call `tableData.get(0).get(1)`.

Comment: you can see the arraylist has 8 rows and 10 columns which means mentioning 1 as row and 2 as column i mean 0th row and 1st column, but it generates no result and give null error.

Comment: `"Value Of Row 1 Col 2: " + tableData.get(1).get(2)` also, is `tableData.get(1).get(2) == null`?

Comment: yes, it generates error null.  i hv also attached picture of html table shown with the data.

Comment: `tableData.get(1).get(2)` is `null`. You are attempting to print a null variable, which invokes `java.lang.Object.toString()`. (Maps and other classes extend java.lang.Object) You are attempting to call null.toString(). This does not exist, so it throws a variable. Try defining `tableData.get(1).get(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Fianlly with the help of LHCHIN, the key was header 0, header 1 etc and it worked great. finally i wrote: tableData.get(1).get("header 2").getValue() and it worked perfectly.